# What does currentState here means

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
this.state = { isOpen: false };


onClickHandler() {
        this.setState(currentState => ({
          isOpen: !currentState.isOpen
        }));
      }
```

There is only one state here,isOpne,but when i set a state ,there i see currentState, what does this means

Comment: What does here currentState means

Comment: previous state which you have stored previously

Comment: what if i not use currentState..?

Comment: you probably dont need it. `setState({isOpen: !currentState.isOpen})`

Comment: it will work without currentState too

Comment: So it is optional right..

Comment: Try `setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})` instead. I guess it'll work too.

Comment: @MayankPandav very thanks, am just a beginner

Comment: @JoeLloyd Lloyd, very thanks, am just a beginner

Comment: ok no problem follow my answer if you like then do upvote and mark it right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in above example currentState is previous state which you have used before when you have multiple items like many users list and want to compare and want to neglate some of them with true false then you can use but for toggle state you can simply use below code:

```
this.state = { isOpen: false };


onClickHandler() {
        this.setState({
          isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
      }
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. That's why I wrote it in a comment.

Comment: dear what does currentstate mean include this answer hope you understand quetion

Answer (score 0):

To calculate new state using the current state, you can very well do:

```
this.state = { isOpen: false };


onClickHandler() {
        this.setState(currentState => ({
          isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        }));
      }
```

However this is bad practice as mentioned in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> State Updates May Be Asynchronous. React may batch multiple setState()
>   calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and
>   this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their
>   values for calculating the next state.

Thus when we need to calculate next state from the current state, the `setState` provides access to the current state as `setState(myCurrentState => {...});`. You can even access `props` as the second parameter like `setState((myCurrentState, myProps) => {...});`.

So in your case `currentState` simply refers to your component state at the given moment just before the state update that's going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

> what does this means?

If you go to the docs there you can find that there are two ways to update the state.

1. Via using object way
2. Via passing a function.

#### 1.

With this you need to pass just the property of the state object to update. like:

```
this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
```

#### 2.

In this case you are naming it as `currentState` it refers to the previous state, which is not yet updated.

```
this.setState(currentState => ({ // <---currentState is named as prevState in docs
      isOpen: !currentState.isOpen
}));
```

You can think of it as `this.state`.